# is `column` a valid mysql column name?

Tags: mysql, syntax

In mySql I was trying to modify the table "m_category" like this:

```
update m_category set column = 1
where uppermodel = true;
```

but after some error messages I realized that the name of the column is... "column"! I did not create the DB, how can I override the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a different column name. It is not a good idea to use reserved words/keywords as column name

Comment: I cannot modify db structure, I can barely modify the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to escape reserved words and special characters in names

```
set `column` = 1
```

Comment: perfect! it does the trick :) I tryed also with ***update m_category set m_category.column = 1 where uppermodel = true;*** and worked fine too. Thanks!